# updating image position on canvas on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, canvas

I have a method to draw nodes (ellipses) on a canvas at mouse click, and then when clicking on one of those nodes, a method does some calculations based on that node's x,y and places an image of whatever file-path I put in the code. I'm trying to make it so when I click on another node, the image's location is updated based on the new node's x, y. I tried doing what was listed here [Draw rectangle and update it on every mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246345/draw-rectangle-and-update-it-on-every-mouse-click), but it's not removing the last image.

Here's my method for the button click that starts this -

```
    private void FindROVButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (SelectedNode != null) // SelectedNode is the currently clicked node
        {
            if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Calculate ROV location from \"" + SelectedNode.Name + "\"?", "Calculate ROV Location", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {

                Point rovPosition = new Point();
                rovPosition = calculateROV_position(SelectedNode.X, SelectedNode.Y, SelectedNode.Range, SelectedNode.Bearing);


                Image rov = new Image();
                rov.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Pic\\Example.png"));
                rov.Width = 30;
                rov.Height = 30;

                Canvas.SetLeft(rov, (rovPosition.X - (rov.Width / 2.0)));
                Canvas.SetTop(rov, (rovPosition.Y - (rov.Height / 2.0)));

                canvas1.Children.Add(rov);
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling canvas1.Children.Remove(rov) anywhere before the new rov is placed on the canvas doesn't work. It just always adds a new one to the canvas. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it's all based off of the selected node.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to first create the new Image before the method, and then have the canvas1.Children.Remove(rov) in the method before the canvas1.Children.Add(rov).

```
Image rov = new Image();
private void FindROVButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (SelectedNode != null)
    {
        if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Calculate ROV location from \"" + SelectedNode.Name + "\"?", "Calculate ROV Location", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {

                Point rovPosition = new Point();
                rovPosition = calculateROV_position(SelectedNode.X, SelectedNode.Y, SelectedNode.Range, SelectedNode.Bearing);

                rov.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:\\Dev\\trunk\\Software\\Nav Assist\\Data\\Hull Cleaner Tiny Image.png"));
                canvas1.Children.Remove(rov);

                rov.Width = 30;
                rov.Height = 30;

                Canvas.SetLeft(rov, (rovPosition.X - (rov.Width / 2.0)));
                Canvas.SetTop(rov, (rovPosition.Y - (rov.Height / 2.0)));

                canvas1.Children.Add(rov);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine.